Alerta de falta de saldo en la cuenta en Google ADS
Hola estoy realizando un script en JS el cual debe mandar una notificacion por mail cuando el presupuesto actual de la cuenta se encuentra por debajo del 5%:
var CONFIG = {
    EMAIL: 'juan@gmail.com', // Dirección de correo electrónico donde se enviará la alerta.
    PORCENTAJE_ALERTA: 5 // Porcentaje del presupuesto máximo al cual se disparará la alerta.
};

function main() {
    // Calcula el presupuesto máximo permitido para la cuenta en el mes actual.
    var totalBudget = 0;

    // Itera sobre todas las campañas activas para sumar sus presupuestos diarios.
    var campaignIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns()
        .withCondition("Status = ENABLED")
        .get();

    while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
        var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
        var dailyBudget = campaign.getBudget().getAmount();
        Logger.log("Campaña: " + campaign.getName() + " - Presupuesto diario: " + dailyBudget);
        totalBudget += dailyBudget; // Suma el presupuesto diario de cada campaña activa
    }

    Logger.log("Presupuesto diario total de todas las campañas activas: " + totalBudget);

    // Multiplica por 30 para obtener el presupuesto mensual aproximado
    var PRESUPUESTO_MAXIMO = totalBudget * 30;

    Logger.log("Presupuesto mensual calculado: " + PRESUPUESTO_MAXIMO);

    // Calcula el umbral de alerta como el porcentaje configurado del presupuesto máximo.
    var presupuestoUmbral = PRESUPUESTO_MAXIMO * CONFIG.PORCENTAJE_ALERTA / 100;

    Logger.log("Umbral de alerta calculado: " + presupuestoUmbral);

    // Obtiene la cuenta de Google Ads actual en la que se está ejecutando el script.
    var account = AdWordsApp.currentAccount();

    // Define una consulta para obtener el costo total de la cuenta durante el mes en curso.
    var query = 'SELECT Cost FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING THIS_MONTH';

    // Ejecuta la consulta y almacena el resultado en 'report'.
    var report = AdWordsApp.report(query);

    // Obtiene las filas del informe (el informe puede contener varias filas si hay múltiples días de datos).
    var rows = report.rows();

    // Variable para almacenar el costo total
    var costeTotal = 0;

    // Recorre todas las filas obtenidas por la consulta.
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        var row = rows.next(); // Obtiene la siguiente fila del informe.

        // Log de la fila actual.
        Logger.log("Fila de costo actual: " + JSON.stringify(row));

        // Convierte el valor de 'Cost' de la fila a un número flotante.
        var coste = parseFloat(row["Cost"].replace(/,/g, ''));

        Logger.log("Costo actual (antes de sumar al total): " + coste);

        // Suma el costo al costo total
        costeTotal += coste;

        Logger.log("Costo total acumulado hasta ahora: " + costeTotal);
    }

    Logger.log("Costo total calculado hasta la fecha: " + costeTotal);

    // Calcula el presupuesto restante.
    var presupuestoRestante = PRESUPUESTO_MAXIMO - costeTotal;

    Logger.log("Presupuesto restante calculado: " + presupuestoRestante);

    // Verifica si el presupuesto restante está por debajo del umbral de alerta.
    if (presupuestoRestante < presupuestoUmbral) {
        // Si el presupuesto restante está por debajo del umbral, se envía un correo electrónico de alerta.
        MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: CONFIG.EMAIL, // Dirección de correo electrónico a la que se enviará la alerta.
            subject: 'Alerta: Presupuesto de Google Ads por debajo del 5%', // Asunto del correo electrónico.
            htmlBody: account.getName() + " tiene un presupuesto restante de " + presupuestoRestante + " $ pesos, lo que está por debajo del umbral del 5% de " + PRESUPUESTO_MAXIMO + " $ pesos.<br>", // Cuerpo del mensaje.
        });

        // Registra en los logs que se ha enviado un correo electrónico.
        Logger.log("Mail enviado. Presupuesto restante: " + presupuestoRestante + " $ pesos.");
    } else {
        // Si el presupuesto restante no está por debajo del umbral, registra en los logs que no se envía el correo.
        Logger.log("Presupuesto restante: " + presupuestoRestante + " $ pesos. No se envía mail, ya que está por encima del umbral de alerta.");
    }

    Logger.log("Script completado.");
}

Esto es lo que obtengo como salida:
Campaña: dycsa-search-novaterra - Presupuesto diario: 1250
Presupuesto diario total de todas las campañas activas: 1250
Presupuesto mensual calculado: 37500
Umbral de alerta calculado: 1875
Fila de costo actual: {"Cost":"49,891.44"}
Costo actual (antes de sumar al total): 49891.44

Costo total acumulado hasta ahora: 49891.44
Costo total calculado hasta la fecha: 49891.44

Presupuesto restante calculado: -12391.440000000002

Mail enviado. Presupuesto restante: -12391.44000002$pesos.

Script completado.

Tengo 5 campañas activas y me esta tomando solo 1 no encuentro el error ademas de que el mail no deberia enviarse ya que mi presupuesto no esta por debajo de dicho porcentaje.

Pero lo que esta haciendo es correcto... -12391 es menor que 49891...

Si pero la comparacion que se esta haciendo no es la adecuada me trae el gasto diario con respecto a 1 sola campaña y no a 5

Entonces tu problema esta aca?  while (campaignIterator.hasNext())???  si ahi viene una sola campaña, verifica porque viene una sola y no 5...
